# Is there a Leaflet for Dummies or Leaflet 101

Tags: leaflet, references

I am very interested in learning leaflet, but I am not a programer nor a cartographer. Is there any LEAFLET for DUMMIES course that I can take?

Comment: What are you trying to do? packtpub.com has a couple of books which are quite decent for the price.

Answer (score 1):

I just googled and found the [Leaflet Quick Start Guide](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html):

> This step-by-step guide will quickly get you started on Leaflet
>   basics, including setting up a Leaflet map, working with markers,
>   polylines and popups, and dealing with events.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout "Leaflet.js Succinctly" by SyncFusion. It's about 100 pages. A few acquaintances have said it's a good read.

You can download it from https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/ebooks.